# Questions about boundary constraints with L-BFGS-B method in optim() in R

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to use L-BFGS-B method in optim() to find out the minimum value of the following function:

```
ip<-function(x) log(mean(exp(return*x))) , where "return" is a series of constants.
```

First, I gave no boundary constraints: `rst1<-optim (-1,ip,method="L-BFGS-B")`, and it provided a reasonable answer `(x=-118.44,ip.min=-0.00017)`, which could be justified by both theory and excel calculation. The given message in the result was

> CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL.

As x must be less than zero in theory, I then added boundary constraints to the optimizer: `rst2<-optim (-1,ip,method="L-BFGS-B",lower=-Inf,upper=0)`. However, this time it only provided an answer calculated by the initial parameter (-1), which is obviously not the minimum value. The given message in the result was

> CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH.

I then tried other boundary constraints, and no matter what they were, as long as boundary constraints were added here, it would always provided an answer calculated by the initial parameter, and failed to find the minimum value.

Does anyone know why this happens? Many thanks.

---

##### example

```
rtntxt<-"
return
9.15051E-05
9.67217E-07
1.34187E-05
-0.000105801
0.000111004
0.000228786
3.84068E-06
0.000388639
-0.000122291
-7.73028E-05
4.97595E-05
-3.97503E-05
1.86449E-05
-0.000137739
-0.000180709
-1.07254E-05
3.89723E-05
"

rtn<-read.table(text=rtntxt,header=TRUE)

ip<-function(x) log(mean(exp(rtn$return*x)))

rst1<-optim(-1,ip,method="L-BFGS-B")  #no boundaries

rst2<-optim(-1,ip,method="L-BFGS-B",lower=-Inf,upper=0)  #with boundaries
```

##### plot

```
x<- -10000:10000

n<-length(x)

s<-numeric(n)

for(i in 1:n) s[i]<-ip(x[i])

plot(x,s)

x[which(s==min(s))] #rst1(no boundaries) is correct

min(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how did you get that result: If I correct your code for misspelling I still get similar answers, and not the answer you got from your result:

```
ip<-function(x) log(mean(exp(return(x))))
rst1<-optim(-1,ip,method="L-BFGS-B")
# > rst1
# $`par`
# [1] -1.820444e+13
# 
# $value
# [1] -1.820444e+13
# 
# $counts
# function gradient 
# 20       20 
# 
# $convergence
# [1] 0
# 
# $message
# [1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
# 

rst2<-optim (-1,ip,method="L-BFGS-B",lower=-Inf,upper=0)
# $`par`
# [1] -1.80144e+13
# 
# $value
# [1] -1.80144e+13
# 
# $counts
# function gradient 
# 3        3 
# 
# $convergence
# [1] 0
# 
# $message
# [1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```

Moreover, to check whether there could be a mistake on my code, I tried to plot the values of you function for -1:-100000, but It does not look like there exist an optim where you tell there is. Check your code/post, and if you know approximately where the optimum value is, try to plot it graphically ( that would be my advise). Cheers !,

```
plot(x = -1:-100000, y = ip(-1:-100000))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The "return" in function "ip" is actually a time series of stock excess returns, each of which is multiplied by x. I have modified my question and added some example data. If you use that return series, the one with boundaries will give a wrong result.

However, I have also found that if you only use the first 10 returns in the example data, the one with boundaries will give the right result (so confusing!).

Could you please help me check it out? Thanks.

Comment: Can you write your code in the example nice ? such that I can check :) It is not a good idea to call something return, because are can get mistaken with the `return()` part of the function. Instead, call it for instance "returns"

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I did not realize that “return” is the name of a function in R. The good news is that I have found where goes wrong. It has been clear that when the objective function’s value is in very small scale while boundary constraints are set, the “L-BFGS-B” method will give a wrong result. After I multiplied the objective function by 100, it managed to find the actual minimum value. As R gives no warning messages throughout the whole process, it is worth some attention.

Comment: Nice !, perfect